# I need CRON expression for every 90 seconds (1min. 30 sec). Is it possible?

Tags: .net, cron, hangfire

I need to run my recurring job for every 90 seconds (1min. 30 seconds). What is the CRON expression for this. Is it possible to do this?

The below code is scheduled my job in every 2 minutes. But i want to schedule for every 90 seconds (1min. 30 seconds)

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Send Alert", x => x.SendAlert(null), "* /2 * * * *");

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? Please share what pattern you tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi I am using HangFire with .Net for scheduling my job and I want to schedule the recurring job for every 90 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

create one crontab entry that runs X every 3 minutes on the minutes (*/3 * * * *), and a second crontab entry that runs X every 3 minutes with an offset of 30 seconds (1/3 * * * * sleep 30 && command)

```
*/3 * * * * command
1/3 * * * * sleep 30 && command
```

Comment: Hi @Riccardo Venturini, Thanks for your help. I am new to CRON expression and hangfire. Could you please explain, how i am using your expression with hangfire?